# render a Zend_View_Helper_FormElement without making it part of a Zend_Form

Tags: php, zend-framework, datatables

I have create a Zend Framework view helper to show a list of database results.
The view helper applies the jQuery DataTables plugin and it extends the Zend_View_Helper_FormElement.

It needs to be a FormElement because it should be wrapped by a form for pagination amongst other things.

Currently I create a Zend_Form, add the DataTables-Element and pass it to the view.

What I would really like to do is:
create an instance of the DataTables-Element and pass it to the view.
When rendering, it should wrap itself in a Zend_Form.
But: how does the DataTables-Element knows that it already is part of a Zend_Form?
In other words: the render function should also render an form-element when the element is not a part of a form.

Comment: the elements do not know they are part of the form, the form know which are its elements when you use `$form->addElement($element)`. You could use the viewhelper of the element directly into the view, there are number of examples into the documentation

Answer (score 0):

You can use zend view helpers to render various form elements which is not parts of a form like this:

```
echo $this->formText('elementID', 'value', array( 'size' => 20,
                                                  'class' => 'foo')
                     );
```

There are lot of [inital helpers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial) to render form elements in zend way.